# What is the difference between "das Ergebnis" and "die Folge"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

They both are translated as result, but it seems that their language use is not the same.
Can somebody explain their proper use?

Comment: That can't be the only translation, which dictionary did you use? Compare http://www.dict.cc/?s=folge with http://www.dict.cc/?s=ergebnis.

Comment: [consequence->Folge – outcome->Ergebnis](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=result&l=deen&in=&lf=en)

Comment: I use GoogleChrome extension Instant Translate

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a native speaker and it's actually not that difficult, even though they are quite similar.

While "die Folge" is more like the consequence (so something that follows which doesn't finish it completely, like a secondary result I guess), the word "das Ergebnis" is more like a (final) outcome which finishes (for example a research) completely.

Comment: +1 for "consequence" which is the appropriate 'general' translation for "Folge".

Comment: "Der Kopfball hatte das zwischenzeitliche 2:3 zum Ergebnis" kann gesagt werden, ohne dass das 2:3 auch das finale Ergebnis ist. Umgekehrt kann man auch sagen, dass der Elfmeter das 2:4 zur Folge hatte, auch wenn das 2:4 das endgültige Ergebnis ist. Die Antwort ist also in jeder Hinsicht falsch.

Comment: @userunknown: Das 2:3 ist nicht das Ergebnis des *Spiels*, sondern das Ergebnis des *Kopfballs*, der mit dem gefallenen Tor definitiv beendet war, während das Spiel weiterlief.

Comment: @celtschk: Tja, das Ergebnis des Kopfballs oder die Folge des Kopfballs war das 2:3. Was willst Du sagen? Dass ein Ergebnis nicht eine vorläufige Folge sein kann, oder dass eine Folge nicht Ergebnis genannt werden kann? Oder was sonst? "Folge ... doesn't finish it completely" - which it? Wo nimmst Du das Spiel her, wenn vom Kopfball die Rede ist? Oder: Welches Folge kann nicht als Ergebnis eines Teilbereichs so aufgefasst werden, dass sie ein Zwischenergebnis ist?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich wollte damit sagen, dass das 2:3 durchaus das *finale* Ergebnis des Kopfballs war, selbst wenn es nicht das Ergebnis des Spiels war, und somit Dein diesbezügliches Argument nicht stichhaltig ist.

Comment: @celtschk: Ob eine Folge etwas Finales ist, ist eine Frage der Perspektive, wie Dein Beispiel mit dem Kopfball zeigt. Solange diese Perspektive aber offen ist, und nicht näher bestimmt, sind eben beide Wendungen möglich. Auch lässt sich für fast jedes Ergebnis ein größerer Rahmen finden, in dem es nur vorläufig war - etwa das Spiel im Turnier, das Turnier in der Karriere usw.

Comment: @userunknown: Worauf sich der Begriff bezieht, steht unmittelbar im Satz. "Das Ergebnis des Kopfballs" beziehgt sich eindeutig und ohne jeden Raum für Interpretation auf den Kopfball, während "das Ergebnis des Spiels" sich ebenso eindeutig aufs Spiel bezieht. Etwas anderes wäre es, wenn "das Ergebnis" ohne nähere Spezifikation da stünde, aber das war eben hier nicht der Fall: Es war explizit vom "Ergebnis *des Kopfballs*" die Rede.

Comment: @celtschk Eben. Und so ist das Ergebnis des Kopfballs nicht von der Folge des Kopfballs zu unterscheiden. Es freut mich, dass ich Dich so überzeugen konnte, dass Du schon meinst, Du hättest mich überzeugt. :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to add that *Folge* has multiple meanings, e.g. *episode* (of TV series), *sequence* (math), ... Basically it's something that *follows* in some way.
As a connotation there may be something that follows in turn, making it **not** final as explained in the other answers.

Note the similarity of ***Fol**ge* and ***fol**low*. This is not coincidence but due to a common etymology. The Old English *folgian* only later became *follow*.
Cf. [Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Folge) and [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=follow).

Answer (score 4):

IMHO "Folge" (in the result-like sense) emphasizes causality or a similarly strong link.

Ergebnis is often more specific, e.g. you'd say that things falling towards the center of earth is die Folge of the law of gravity. Whereas the Ergebnis of some calculation is 42. If you want to emphasize that the result is obtained by a logical sequence of thoughts:

> Das Ergebnis folgt aus Anwendung von (1) und (2)

in that case, you can also say

> Die Folge aus (1) und (2) ist ...

You can describe situations where the result "happens", independent of which of a number of theoretically possible alternatives is actually right:

> Jedenfalls war das Ergebnis ...

Comment: Especially good on your last point, which adds meaning to what the difference is all about. As a German-experienced native English speaker...

Comment: Der erste, hervorgehobene Satz beinhaltet die Folge als Verb. Der zweite kann auch "Das Ergebnis aus (1) und (2) ist ...". Ebenso ist "Jedenfalls war die Folge ..."  möglich und üblich. Außerdem ist das Fallen von Gegenständen Richtung Erdmittelpunkt keine Folge des Gesetzes der Gravitation, sondern eine Folge der Gravitation selbst. Oder deren Ergebnis. Nur im Satz mit der Kalkulation läßt sich Ergebnis nicht mit *Folge* ersetzen.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker I would say that *Ergebnis* is a final thing and *Folge* means that something happens after something was done or happened.

If you say "Das Ergebnis von 1+1 ist 2.", then this is a final result.
*Folge* describes an occurring after something:

> Ich habe den Topf auf den Herd gestellt. Die *Folge* war, dass das Wasser gekocht hat.
>   Der Film war zu Ende. Es *folgte* eine Werbepause.

It's really hard to explain, because these words are very similar, but I hope this helped a bit.

Comment: Yes, it does help!

Comment: Für das Verb *folgte* im Zshg. mit der Werbepause gibt es zwar keinen Ersatz mit *Ergebnis*, aber auch keinen mit Folge, dem Hauptwort. Möglich ist auch zu sagen, dass das Ergebnis war, dass das Wasser gekocht hat. Der Satz "Folge describes an occuring after something" schließt nicht aus, dass *Ergebnis* auch nach einem anderen Ereignis folgt, und zwar in beiden Fällen kausal - die Stellung in der Argumentation legt aber eine Ausschließlichkeit nahe - sonst wäre es ja kein Unterschied, nach dem gefragt war.

Answer (score 2):

#### Folge

is mostly used to illustrate **negative, unwanted consequences**. If you look up "[Folge](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Folge)" in the *Duden*, you will notice that all (!) examples under the relevant first meaning are of negative consequences:

> - unangenehme, verhängnisvolle, katastrophale, schwerwiegende Folgen
> - die zwangsläufige Folge [davon] war, dass sie sich vollends verschloss
> - die Folgen sind noch gar nicht abzusehen
> - etwas kann üble, böse Folgen haben, nach sich ziehen
> - die Folgen tragen müssen ([für etwas] zur Verantwortung gezogen werden)
> - er starb an den Folgen eines Unfalls
> - das Verhältnis blieb nicht ohne Folgen (verhüllend; aus dieser Beziehung ging ein Kind hervor)
> - das Unwetter hatte schwere Schäden zur Folge (führte zu schweren Schäden)

There is not one example of positive consequences!

*I would say that "result" is not a good translation of "Folge". I think "consequences" is better.*

#### Ergebnis

describes the **final outcome** or result in a more neutral manner. "Ergebnisse" can be both negative or positive:

> - ein mageres, günstiges, positives, kein befriedigendes, kein Ergebnis

---

*Please note that both "Folge" and "Ergebnis" have other meanings beside "result/consequences". I did not mention them here since they don't pertain to your question.*

Comment: Good catch. "Folge" indeed seems to be mainly used for negative consequences (so does the English word, too?). It's worth noting, however, that the verb "folgen" and the adverbs "folglich" and "infolgedessen" are not restricted to negative statements.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Ergebnis" is used mainly for intended consequences/results, while "Folge" is used more for unintended consequences (which may explain what's observation that it is most often used for negative consequences: Usually negative consequences are unintended, while people like to claim positive consequences of their actions as intended, even if they didn't really foresee them).

An example of a positive use of "Folge" where I would not say "Ergebnis":

> Er wurde oft mit dem Direktor verwechselt, was zur Folge hatte, dass die anderen Angestellten ihm außerordentlich respektvoll begegneten.

On the other hand, the following use of "Ergebnis" is for a quite negative result, but I'd nevertheless consider it preferable to "Folge":

> Das Ergebnis des Amoklaufs waren fünf Tote und etliche Verletzte.

However the next sentence might be:

> Die Folge war, dass die Sicherheitsmaßnahmen verschärft wurden.

Here, again, I think "Ergebnis" wouldn't fit because the person running amok most probably didn't intend the security measures to be made stricter.

Answer (score 0):

Vorsicht vor falschen Dichotomien!

Wie so oft versuchen die Teilnehmer einen Unterschied in die Bedeutung der Wörter hineinzugeheimnissen, der dort nicht ist.

Es gibt in Ursache-Wirkungs-Beziehungen die Wirkung sowohl als Ergebnis als auch als Folge. Ein Unterschied existiert da nicht. Es gibt vorläufige Ergebnisse, und auch endgültige Ergebnisse sind Folgen.

Wenn ein Ereignis nur später, aber nicht Wirkung war, ist es weder Folge noch Ergebnis.

Nur bei mathematischen Gleichungen nennt man eine angestrebte Vereinfachung **Ergebnis**, nicht **Folge**, wie Eric richtig schrieb, und NoAnswer hat richtig herausgestellt, dass Folge auch Episode oder Sequenz bedeuten kann.